# How to force SQL Server to return empty JSON array

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQL Server 2016, which supports `JSON PATH` to return JSON string.
I wonder how to get just a simple empty json array, I mean `[]` when my query or sub-query returns null. I've tried this query:

```sql
SELECT '' AS TEST
FOR JSON PATH,ROOT('arr')
```

which returns:

```json
{"arr":[{"test":""}]}
```

and also this one:

```sql
SELECT NULL AS TEST
FOR JSON PATH,ROOT('arr')
```

which returns:

```json
{"arr":[{}]}
```

it's better but still not correct, I need this:

```json
{"arr":[]}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can always check this with ISNULL, e.g.:

```
select ISNULL( (SELECT * FROM sys.tables where 1=2 FOR JSON PATH), '[]')
```

If you need this in app layer, maybe it would be better to check is there some results set in data access code, and if not just return [] or {}.

Comment: Thanks for the ISNULL solution suggestion. So simple and it just works!

Answer (score 12):

This works, and can be composed within another `for json` query:

```
select json_query('[]') arr 
    for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

Answer (score 5):

When nesting such subqueries, I've found that combining what others have said works best, i.e.:

- Using `COALESCE((SELECT .. FOR JSON), '[]')` to prevent the `null` value from the subquery
- Using `JSON_QUERY()` to prevent the escaping / quoting.

For example:

```sql
select
  json_query(coalesce((select 1 as b where 1 = 0 for json path), '[]')) as a
for json path;
```

Produces:

```
|JSON      |
|----------|
|[{"a":[]}]|
```

**Without `JSON_QUERY`**

Now the nested json array gets quoted:

```sql
select
  coalesce((select 1 as b where 1 = 0 for json path), '[]') as a
for json path;
```

Results in

```
|JSON        |
|------------|
|[{"a":"[]"}]|
```

**Without `COALESCE`**

Now the nested JSON is `null`:

```sql
select
  json_query((select 1 as b where 1 = 0 for json path)) as a
for json path`;
```

Results in

```
|JSON|
|----|
|[{}]|
```

Comment: When handling Deeply nested subqueries (eg.: relational => documentDB) This is the only answer that hits 100% accuracy every time.

Answer (score 1):

A little manual, but if you need a quick hack, here you go:

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT NULL AS test
FOR JSON PATH,ROOT('arr'))


SELECT REPLACE(@json, '{}', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

By itself, `JSON_QUERY('[]') AS [features]` did not work for me. I found that the results were formatted as follows:

```
"features":"[]"
```

which was not desirable.

To get the desired result, I needed to store the JSON in a variable, then perform a `REPLACE` on the result, as follows:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT JSON_QUERY('[]') AS [features],
                                     -- Other selected fields elided for brevity 
                                FROM MyTable
                                 FOR JSON, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES);

SET @json = REPLACE(@json, '"features":"[]"', '"features":[]');

SELECT @json;
```

Yes, it's a terrible hack. But it works, and returns the result I want. Our client absolutely must have an empty array returned, and this was the best way I could find to ensure that it was present.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I had exactly the same problem, I think this is the right way to handle it according to the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @Array TABLE(TEST VARCHAR(100));

SELECT
    arr = ISNULL((SELECT TEST FROM @Array FOR JSON PATH), '[]')
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Result:

```
{"arr":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [JSON_OBJECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-object-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [JSON_ARRAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-array-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) functions(SQL Server 2022):

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('arr':JSON_ARRAY())
```