# How to have JSON subquery return empty array rather than null when there are no rows

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-json

I have a (hypothetical) JSON schema that calls for a document to look like:

```
[
  {
    "tableName": "Embeddings",
    "object_id": 1301579675,
    "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
    "create_date": "2023-05-03T19:41:56.940",
    "indexes": [
      {
        "name": "PK_Embeddings",
        "type_desc": "CLUSTERED",
        "is_unique": true,
        "is_primary_key": true
      },
      {
        "name": "IX_Embeddings_DimValue",
        "type_desc": "NONCLUSTERED",
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_primary_key": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which you can generate using the query:

```
SELECT 
    t.Name,
    t.object_id,
    t.type_desc,
    t.create_date,
    (
        SELECT name, type_desc, is_unique, is_primary_key
        FROM sys.indexes si
        WHERE si.object_id = t.object_id
        AND type <> 0
        FOR JSON PATH) indexes
FROM sys.tables t
FOR JSON PATH
```

You'll notice the indexes array.

- if there are indexes, they appear in the array.
- If there are no indexes, **i want the array to be empty**.

But unfortunatly in reality if there are no indexes, the `indexes` array won't be omitted, but instead be omitted:

```
  {
    "Name": "DateTests",
    "object_id": 901578250,
    "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
    "create_date": "2020-01-20T10:56:27.757"
  }
```

when it should return:

```
  {
    "Name": "DateTests",
    "object_id": 901578250,
    "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
    "create_date": "2020-01-20T10:56:27.757",
    "indexes": []
  }
```

How can i instruct SQL Server to return an empty array of results, rather than no array of results, if there are no results, when running a query `FOR JSON`?

---

It's odd that it returns *nothing*, rather than an "empty array", because SQL loves to return an empty set of *something*:

> ```
> SELECT name, type_desc, is_unique, is_primary_key FROM sys.indexes WHERE 0=1
> ```
>
> | name | type_desc | is_unique | is_primary_key |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
>
> ```
> 0 row(s) affected
> ```

It doesn't return **nothing**, it returns an *empty* **something**.

So how i can i make JSON return an *empty something*?

## Bonus Reading

- BOL: [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [How to force SQL Server to return empty JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566443/how-to-force-sql-server-to-return-empty-json-array) *(returns a string rather than an array)*
- [How to generate empty JSON array in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322948/how-to-generate-empty-json-array-in-sql-server) *(returns a string rather than an array)*
- [How to return empty JSON array from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610572/how-to-return-empty-json-array-from-sql-server) *(returns a string rather than an array)*

**Edit**: For those who *voted to close as a duplicate*; you completely missed the fact that specifically mentioned that question you linked, and rejected it already. So, please don't close questions when you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: That's a good question. I don't actually know of a direct way to do that. For very simple examples, you might be able to do some string manipulation (very carefully). Although you're probably better off running your JSON through some other processing layer if you need empty arrays rendered (e.g python, jq, js, etc.). Although I'd love to be proved wrong too! MSSQL's JSON support is "good enough" in my mind, but not super mature. There are definitely things that you can do when manipulating JSON in general which you can't do in SQL specifically.

Comment: Not an empty array [], but  FROM sys.tables t FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES will return "indexes": null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2022+ then you can wrap your subquery in an `ISNULL` and then return an empty JSON array with `JSON_ARRAY`:

```sql
SELECT t.Name,
       t.object_id,
       t.type_desc,
       t.create_date,
       ISNULL((SELECT i.name,
                      i.type_desc,
                      i.is_unique,
                      i.is_primary_key
               FROM sys.indexes i
               WHERE i.object_id = t.object_id
               AND type <> 0
               FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES),JSON_ARRAY()) indexes
FROM sys.tables t
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES;
```

If you're not in 2022+, then you could just use `'[]'`, which does work as well.

In `master` this resulted in:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "spt_fallback_db",
        "object_id": 117575457,
        "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
        "create_date": "2003-04-08T09:18:01.557",
        "indexes": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "spt_fallback_dev",
        "object_id": 133575514,
        "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
        "create_date": "2003-04-08T09:18:02.870",
        "indexes": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "spt_fallback_usg",
        "object_id": 149575571,
        "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
        "create_date": "2003-04-08T09:18:04.180",
        "indexes": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "spt_monitor",
        "object_id": 580913141,
        "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
        "create_date": "2023-10-16T16:35:22.277",
        "indexes": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "MSreplication_options",
        "object_id": 2107154552,
        "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
        "create_date": "2019-06-19T13:20:55.087",
        "indexes": []
    }
]
```

db<>fiddles: [2019](https://dbfiddle.uk/97Qjg8U4), [2022](https://dbfiddle.uk/0oZOJdU7)

Answer (score 1):

If <2022, here is another option.   Not as pretty as Thom A's +1  :)

```
SELECT 
    t.Name,
    t.object_id,
    t.type_desc,
    t.create_date,
    ( json_query(
        coalesce( 
        (
        SELECT name, type_desc, is_unique, is_primary_key
        FROM sys.indexes si
        WHERE si.object_id = t.object_id
        AND type <> 0
        FOR JSON PATH) 
        ,( select '[]') )
        )
     ) indexes
FROM sys.tables t FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Comment: Why the nested `select '[]'`

Comment: @Charlieface Shot in the dark to get desired empty array.

Comment: Just do a normal `'[]'` by itself?